# Zend - static and dynamic route

Tags: php, zend-framework

How should I prepare my routes to deal with it, instead of addictional parts in url?

```
$routes = array(
/**
 * Static
 */
'news' => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('news/:page',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => 1 )
),

/**
 * Dynamic
 */
'thread' => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':slug/:page',
    array('controller' => 'Thread', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => 1 )
),
```

e.g. example.com/**thread-name-slug** it shows thread with slug **thread-name-slug**  but when I visit example.com/**news** it wants to show thread with slug **news**. I want static page here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve, to deal with dynamic routes only, without any static ones ?

Answer (score 0):

The router matches routes in *reverse* order of their declaration. Given the request url `/news`, the router will attempt to match first against the route `:slug/:page` and, of course, finds a match, so it never gets to examine your `news/:page` route.

The solution is to reverse the order in which you declare the routes. Generally speaking, one wants to add generic routes before specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

As the latest version of zendframework is 3.x I'll post a sample solution for Zf3, because it's not easy a complete article on zend routes.

Supouse you wanna centralize your admin requests by using only one controller; so you can check permisions, roles, etc in order to serve your site's admin pages.
We'll perform the next tasks:

1. Edit the "module.config.php" file to have a easy to read code.
2. Create a DefineRoutes.php file
3. Write a simple regular expression to set wildcard matching places for all posible admin tasks.

I'll supouse we creates an admin module properly registered in "modules.config.php" file

Editing the module.config.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Filename: zendframework/module/Admin/config/module.config.php
 * The module required settings.
 * @author: your name here
*/
return [
  'controllers' => [
    'factories' => include __DIR__ . '/ControllerFactories.php'
  ],
  'router'      => [
    'routes' => include __DIR__ . '/DefineRoutes.php',
  ],
  'view_manager' => ['template_path_stack' => [__DIR__ . '/../view',],],
];
```

Note: we do not use the close tag ?> in our files

Creating the "DefineRoutes.php" file.

```
<?php
/**
 * @Filename: zendframework/module/Admin/config/DefineRoutes.php
 * Declares site's admin routes
 * @author: your name here
*/
namespace Admin;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

// first a couple of useful functions to make our life easy:
// Creates a regexp to match all case-variants of a word
function freeCaseExt($toCase){
    $len = strlen($toCase);
    $out = '';
    if($len < 1){ return $out; }
    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        $s = strtolower(substr($toCase, $i, 1));
        $out .= '['.$s.strtoupper($s).']';
    } 
    return $out;
}
// To append slash child routes elsewhere
function SlashUri($controller, $action){
    return [
        'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Literal::class, 
        'options' => [
            'route' => '/', 
            'defaults' => ['controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action ]]];
}

$adminvariants = freeCaseExt('admin'); // to constrain our main route

// Our route family tree:
'admin' => [
    'type'    => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route'     => '/:admin[/:case][/:casea][/:caseb][/:casec][/:cased][/:casee][/:casef][/:caseg][/:caseh]',
        'constraints' => [ 
          'admin' => $adminvariants,
          'case'  => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'casea' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'caseb' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'casec' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'cased' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'casee' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'casef' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'caseg' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          'caseh' => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
        ],
        'defaults'  => [
            'controller' => Controller\AdminController::class,
            'action'     => 'index'
        ]
    ],
    'may_terminate' => TRUE,
    'child_routes' => [
        'adminslash' => SlashUri(Controller\AdminController::class, 'index'),
    ]
],
// Now you have declared all the posible admin routes with or without
// slaches '/' at 9 deep levels using the AdminController::Index() method 
// to decide wath to do.
```

**IMPORTANT: As we defined a first level wildcard *:admin* a proper constraint is *required* or it overlaps other first level routes.**

The controllers logics is a few out of skope.
Hope this idea helps somebody.

Luis